# Can I disable default JavaScript operators or functions?

Tags: javascript

I have been adding Feature Policy Headers to my pages and was wondering if there is a way to do something similar for functions or operators in Javascript?

So, for example, I try to always use triple equals and never use double equals. So can I disable the double equals operator?

I am already using JSDoc with TypeScript checking and linting to check my code when I am writing it. 
I am interested in finding out if it is possible to disable operators and default functions when the code runs in the browser.

If it is possible to override the operators to remove them and remove some of the default functions, I was going to try and see if removing these and just using a subset of functions would speed up the run time for some code.

Comment: The standard does not provide anything like that. PS: it's also not obvious how removing those would make any difference.

Comment: If you have a textual reference to the code that's running, you could check to see if it includes `==` not bounded by another `=`.

Comment: The only way you could do it is using `eval` and `replace`, but that's bad.

Comment: I suppose you could write your own custom Javascript engine that throws when Abstract Equality Comparison is used, but that's silly.

Comment: What sort of default functions are you interested in disabling?

Comment: "*I try to always use triple equals and never use double equals*" is a matter of preference. Use a linter. If it's only your code, why do you need to do this? If you're using libraries, it's a sure way to break them.

Comment: @CertainPerformance an example of a default function I would disable would be "getElementsByClassName" and instead I would only use "querySelector".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to disable Javascript *operators*, like `==`, but most built-in *functions* can be changed. For example, for `document.getElementsByClassName`, simply assign your own custom function to `document.getElementsByClassName`:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName = () => {
  throw new Error('Use querySelectorAll instead');
};

const divs = document.getElementsByClassName('div');
```

You can also prevent `getElementsByClassName` from being called on *elements* by assigning over `Element.prototype`:

```js
Element.prototype.getElementsByClassName = () => {
  throw new Error('Use querySelectorAll instead');
};
const childs = div.getElementsByClassName('foo');
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a task for a linter, imo:

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/eqeqeq